How to create arrange and clean up fixtures with Pytest and SQLAlchemy
I'm working on a project that involves database interactions with Python that I'm resolving using the SQLAlchemy ORM. For the testing I'll be using the pytest framework.
I've decided to use a local testing database. I'm using a Docker container to run the server, but the database and the tables will be created by the tests.
For the tests, I'm trying to create two main fixtures:

The first one to set up the database and tables, which is expected to be run once per test session.
The second one to truncate the existing tables, which is expected to be run with each test execution.

For example, let's say we have a models.py module with a Base model inheriting from SQLAlchemy's DeclarativeBase model. Let's say we've defined some customized models from Base. Then let's move to tests/conftest.py module. My approach:
import pytest
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy_utils import create_database, database_exists

from src.models import *


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_session():
    connection_str = ''
    engine = create_engine(connection_str)

    # Ensure the database and the tables exist
    if not database_exists(engine.url):
        create_database(engine.url)

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session


@pytest.fixture()
def truncate_tables(db_session):
    db_tables = list(reversed(Base.metadata.sorted_tables))

    with db_session.begin():
        for table in db_tables:
            table.delete()

My questions:

It is a good approach to use a dedicated local server for testing from a container and to populate it in the tests?
How would you design the fixtures above? Particularly, I cannot make the second one to work as expected.

